# Unable to show string on 2x16 LCD display

Tags: pi-3, gpio, lcd

connected 2x16 LCD display to raspberry pi 3.I followed above tutorial

https://www.rototron.info/lcd-display-tutorial-for-raspberry-pi/

I made connections as shown in the tutorial.Install adafruit charLCD library.After power on raspberry Pi ,back light of 2x16 LCD is activated and getting 16 black boxes on display screen. But unable to show any string on LCD display.

please help.

Answer (score 1):

As you say you have done everything else correctly the only possibility is that the contrast on the LCD screen is wrong.  There should be a contrast adjustment.

Comment: can you guide me ,how to adjust contrast for 2x16 LCD display,as I am not aware about this much.

Comment: @Manorama If it can be adjusted there is likely to be a small pot on the back of the screen.  They normally have a slot for a small screwdriver to turn and adjust the contrast.

Comment: i tried with potentiometer to adjust contrast,and with this now I am able to adjust contrast.But still not showing any string character on LCD display.

Comment: In that case you need to edit your question and add photos of your set-up and software listings.

Comment: Please provide  code snippet indicating you hardware setup.Which  function is connected to which pin.  Seeing 2x16 "characters block" only tells you that the LCD went thru its power -up routine successfully - nothing else.